# C# System.NullReferenceException error Google Calendar

Tags: c#, string, google-calendar-api, nullreferenceexception

I have a program in which I keep getting the NullReferenceException error.  Here is the code that is causing the error:

```
string description = "";
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(eventItem.Description.ToString()))
{
     description = "No description available.";
}
else
{                        
     description = eventItem.Description.ToString();  
}
```

I have looked through this post ([What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it/4660186#4660186)), and I have tried several of the solutions (I'm afraid I simply don't understand all of them enough to try them), but I just can't figure out why this is happening.  In my understanding, this error occurs because the string is in fact null.

There are events on my Google Calendar that have no description entered, so the description is null, but shouldn't the code I have check for that, and handle it?  Or, is the problem that eventItem.Description.ToString() cannot be null when I call the IsNullOrEmpty method?  I have also tried changing the if statement to this:

```
if (eventItem.Description.ToString() == null)
```

...but I still get the NRE error.  I have tried rewriting my code so many different ways, but nothing has worked.  I'm at the end of my rope!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `eventItem` itself may be null. Do something along the lines

```
 if ( eventItem!= null && eventItem.Description != null && eventItem.Description.ToString() == null)
```

Updated after DStanley pointed out in the comment that .ToString() == null comparison would be unnecessary.

```
if ( eventItem!= null && eventItem.Description != null)
{
}
```

Just to help you understand a little better... NullReferenceException basically means you are trying to use some object without instantiating it. One of the simplest way to prevent is to add a null check if you are not sure whether the object is not null. And when I say adding a null check, it simply means comparing to null in the if block before accessing any property of the object.

```
if( objectName != null)
{
//then do something on the object

}
```

Comment: Or `eventItem.Description` could be null.

Comment: Yes. Thank-you, Jack. I updated the answer. Without the information you gave, it may have still thrown the error.

Comment: `ToString` will not return null for any framework types.  Unless `Description` is a custom type that overloads `ToString` to return `null` for a valid value (which would be very strange) the check for `ToString` to be null is unnecessary.

Comment: @DStanley - thanks for pointing that out. Indeed that .ToString() comparision to null will be unnecessary, unless overloaded.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I just removed the .ToString() from that line, and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

> shouldn't the code I have check for that, and handle it?

Not if `item` or `item.Description` is null. If `item` is null then the call to `.Description` will throw a null reference exception, and if `item.Description` is null then the call to `ToString` will throw a null reference exception.  There's no "magic" that lets you call `ToString` on a null reference.

Note that if `item.Description` is already a string then there's no need to call `ToString()`.  just do:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(eventItem.Description))
{
     description = "No description available.";
}
else
{                        
     description = eventItem.Description;  
}
```

Comment: if `eventItem.Description` is null it again Throws the same exception; since  `.ToString()`  will not convert `null` to `""`

Comment: @un-lucky Thanks - I forgot to edit that part of my answer.

Comment: Wouldn't you want to check null for the 'eventItem' object before accessing the 'Description' property?

Comment: Sure, unless it's checked for `null` somewhere else in the code.  The description of the program leads me to assume that the `eventItem` is used elsewhere, so it may have already been checked for null.

Comment: That's correct.  I query the calendar, and then perform the code using the following if statement:                                                                              

    if (events.Items != null && events.Items.Count > 0)